# Contar numero repetidos de forma consecutiva en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

Buen día estimados estoy buscando obtener que me devuelva la cantidad de veces que se repite una operación de forma consecutiva, es decir que NO haya otra operación de por medio.

Lo estoy intentando hacer de la forma siguiente:

```
 select No_Pedido, No_Tienda, Fecha_Operacion, Tipo_Operacion, 1 as Num
 into #Secuencia
 from MOVIMIENTO_PEDIDO



select fNo_Pedido,  No_Tienda,  Fecha_Operacion,  Tipo_Operacion, 
case when Tipo_Operacion=LAG(Tipo_Operacion) over (order by Fecha_Operacion) then num +1 
 else 1 end as Cantidad_Veces_Repetidas
from #Secuencia
```

El resultado que me da es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De ante mano agradezco su valioso apoyo.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Contador de operaciones repetidas de forma consecutivas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/525012/contador-de-operaciones-repetidas-de-forma-consecutivas)

Answer (score 0):

Es ideal para estos casos el uso del [`row_number()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) para enumerar, que permite configurar bajo que condiciones se reinicia (`partition by`) y el orden (`order by`)

```
select No_Pedido, 
       No_Tienda, 
       Fecha_Operacion, 
       Tipo_Operacion,
       row_number() over (partition by No_Pedido, No_Tienda, Tipo_Operacion order by o_Pedido, No_Tienda, Tipo_Operacion) as Num
       from MOVIMIENTO_PEDIDO
```

Comment: agradezco mucho tu ayuda patricio, sin embargo, en la consulta no quiero agrupar el tipo de operación, ya que lo que necesito es que me cuente, por ejemplo cuantas veces se repite la operación 12 de forma consecutiva, pero una ves encuentre otro tipo de operación deje de contar aunque la siguiente que se siga vuelva hacer la operación 12, espero me haya dado a entender.

Comment: No estoy haciendo ninguna agrupación. ¿has llegado a probar este código?